# Infinispan cache.values ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, infinispan

We are using 2 instances of infinispan, with a fileStore (each instance has its own filestore location, just to clarify), The replication is CacheMode.REPL_ASYNC. The version of inifinispan (bundled with JBOSS) is 6.0.2.G1.

The code run just fine for some time, but now we are storing some thousands of keys in the cache.

The code runs org.infinispan.CacheImpl.values() only once at the server start - as it needs to count all keys of a specific types.

Yesterday the second server does not start (only one runs fine), it throws ConcurrentModificationException during iteration I guess:

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: Execution exception!
    at org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.process(SingleFileStore.java:487) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.async.AdvancedAsyncCacheLoader.loadAllKeys(AdvancedAsyncCacheLoader.java:43) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.async.AdvancedAsyncCacheLoader.process(AdvancedAsyncCacheLoader.java:78) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.processOnAllStores(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:414) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheLoaderInterceptor.visitValuesCommand(CacheLoaderInterceptor.java:206) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.ValuesCommand.acceptVisitor(ValuesCommand.java:40) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:98) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:112) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitValuesCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:84) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.ValuesCommand.acceptVisitor(ValuesCommand.java:40) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:98) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:112) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitValuesCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:84) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.ValuesCommand.acceptVisitor(ValuesCommand.java:40) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:98) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:112) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitValuesCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:84) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.ValuesCommand.acceptVisitor(ValuesCommand.java:40) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:98) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:112) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitValuesCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:84) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.ValuesCommand.acceptVisitor(ValuesCommand.java:40) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:98) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleDefault(StateTransferInterceptor.java:249) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitValuesCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:84) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.ValuesCommand.acceptVisitor(ValuesCommand.java:40) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:98) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:112) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitValuesCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:84) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.ValuesCommand.acceptVisitor(ValuesCommand.java:40) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:98) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:112) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitValuesCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:84) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.ValuesCommand.acceptVisitor(ValuesCommand.java:40) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:98) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:110) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:73) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitValuesCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:84) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.ValuesCommand.acceptVisitor(ValuesCommand.java:40) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:333) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.CacheImpl.values(CacheImpl.java:467) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.CacheImpl.values(CacheImpl.java:460) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at MY CODE CALLING cache.values()
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:233) [rt.jar:1.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:94) [rt.jar:1.6.0]
    at org.infinispan.executors.ExecutorAllCompletionService.pollUntilEmpty(ExecutorAllCompletionService.java:48) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.executors.ExecutorAllCompletionService.submit(ExecutorAllCompletionService.java:32) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.process(SingleFileStore.java:469) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    ... 99 more
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$AbstractMapIterator.checkConcurrentMod(HashMap.java:193) [java.util.jar:]
    at java.util.HashMap$AbstractMapIterator.makeNext(HashMap.java:198) [java.util.jar:]
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:271) [java.util.jar:]
    at java.util.HashMap.analyzeMap(HashMap.java:800) [java.util.jar:]
    at java.util.HashMap.rehash(HashMap.java:786) [java.util.jar:]
    at java.util.HashMap.rehash(HashMap.java:819) [java.util.jar:]
    at java.util.HashMap.putImpl(HashMap.java:702) [java.util.jar:]
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:680) [java.util.jar:]
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:102) [java.util.jar:]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.async.AdvancedAsyncCacheLoader$1.processEntry(AdvancedAsyncCacheLoader.java:46) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore$1.call(SingleFileStore.java:475) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore$1.call(SingleFileStore.java:469) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.G1.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314) [rt.jar:1.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149) [rt.jar:1.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:450) [rt.jar:1.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314) [rt.jar:1.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149) [rt.jar:1.6.0]
    ... 3 more
```

If I turn off the filestore and just keep the memory store - the error does not occur. I don't know if there is any problem with Infinispan having that version, or the filestore. Maybe (though there is no mention in documentation) there are some problems with iterating all the keys if there are alot of keys in the cache already and the server is clustered?

I have no idea actually how to diagnose this problem, and the tickets on infinispan do show others having such problem, but not when just calling cache.values(). What might be wrong? Is there any safer way to iterate the cache?

Comment: I guess some replication is happening while the iteration process is running.  The memory store is much faster so the reason why it doesn't happen then is there is less chance for replication to add new data while you are iterating over the cache.

Comment: @john16384 that is my guess too, but I don't expect that this was not taken into account when implementing method values(), nor the infinispan javadoc for that method mentions any dangers

Comment: It looks like you are hitting https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-3938.
edit: can you update to a newer version? Infinispan 9 was released last month.

Comment: @pruivo thanks! I couldn't find any tickets on that. I think we have no choice but to disable file store until we are ready to update infinispan to 8.2+